# Facebook plugin - Recommendations images

Tags: facebook, plugins, widget

Is it possible to display only the images from the [Facebook recommendations plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/)?

Thanks,
Uli

P.S. Why the down vote?

Comment: If you can't do it with their plugin generator you shouldn't do it as it violets the facebook developer terms and conditions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Is there a Facebook API to access the recommendations then?

Comment: Yes, the documentation for it is the link you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no it is not possible as I don't see that option currently for the Facebook recommendations plugin.